# How to compute mathematical expression using string in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent

Hi I have create mathematical expression as string format

```
    String strFormula = "((2*(" + a + "+(2*" + st + "))+2*(" + b + "+(2*" + st + ")))*" + l + "/1000000)*" + amount;
    strFormula = CommonFunctions.FormatFormulaWithGermanStandard(strFormula);
```

I want to evaluate this mathematical expression .

Please suggest me usable link or sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to solve an expression which are by prefix, postfix or infix you can implement or can check java code for one of these methods to solve your expression like here is link below of code for solving an expression using postfix method

http://resume.technoplaza.net/java/postfix-calc.php

by googling you can find more useful links

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 ways you can execute this.

- use SQL lite (inbuilt) db to execute a select statement with the expression
- use google, make a google request with the expression and it will return a response.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to roll your own, [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/) should be able to handle that kind of expression, and it's relatively lightweight.